# list certain folders containg spaces in Cygwin/bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, cygwin

I am trying to create a bash script on Cygwin and Windows Server 2008 R2 that looks up for some folders and moves them around.

The issue seems to be with the folder names as they contain multiple spaces in between.

These folders are all named like this: **SOMENAME - RAF**, where the first part of the name, **SOMENAME** in this case, changes according to the document content, while the second part  **- RAF** is immutable.

I came up with the following example but sadly provides no result:

```
#!/bin/bash

rootdir="E:\cork scew"
workdir="E:\cork scew\temp"
outdir="E:\cork scew\completed"

if [ -d "$(cygpath -u "${rootdir}")/*\ -\ RAF" ];
  then
echo found em
  else
exit 0
fi
```

I have also tried without *cygpath*, thus using the standard unix path but essentially made no difference. 
Folders in this format ***\ -\ RAF** don't seem to be getting found.

Ironically, doing a ls like you normally would on bash does work

```
blahba@locked /cygdrive/e/scum
$ ls /cygdrive/e/cork\ screw/*\ -\ RAF

/cygdrive/e/cork screw/WS0001 - RAF:
TEST1

/cygdrive/e/cork screw/WS0002 - RAF:
TEST1

/cygdrive/e/cork screw/WS0003 - RAF:
TEST1

/cygdrive/e/cork screw/WS0004 - RAF:
TEST1
```

Bash version appears to be *4.3.42(4)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)*. Has anyone got any idea of what all I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `-d` tests whether there's a directory by a particular name, not whether there are any directories matching a wildcard pattern. See [BashFAQ #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) for some better options. Note that you will need to quote or escape the parts of the pattern that contain spaces, but *not* the wildcard(s).

Answer (score 1):

You are including the wildcard and the escaped spaces into the double quotes, which will match that path literally. Plus, if there's more than one match the `test` command can't handle that.

These patterns should work:

```
dirs="$(cygpath -u "${rootdir}")/"*" - RAF"
```

or

```
dirs="$(cygpath -u "${rootdir}")/"*\ -\ RAF
```

And to test if there were any matches you can use something like

```
if [ -n "${dirs}" ]; then
    for dir in ${dirs}; do
        echo "Found ${dir}"
    done
else
    echo "No dir found"
fi
```

Comment: This still won't work right, because the shell expands the wildcard pattern to a *list* of matching files & folders, but `-d` only checks a single file/folder; the extra folder names will cause an error.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson for the hint; I was too focused on the main issue to think of that.

Comment: That worked. Thanks to you both guys. I honestly couldn't get to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Good to hear. Don't forget to accept the answer then.